# How to compute this utility function's expected value.

Tags: expected-value

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quv0N.png)

This is a question of financial economics. There are N stocks,

1. The utility function U is the function of $W_1$ and X, $U(\tilde W_{1i},X_i)$,
2. $W_0$ is the investor's wealth at moment $0$, and $W_1$ is the wealth at
   moment $1$,
3. $r_f$ is the risk-free interest rate, $\tilde r$ be the N × 1 vector which is the excess rate of return,We assume $\tilde r$ is normally distributed,
4. Let $X_i$  denote an N × 1 vector whose nth element is the fraction of agent i’s wealth invested in stock n.
5. $a_i = A_i*W_{0i}$ , Both $a_i$ and $b_i$ are known constants.

How is the last line of formula derived? (the last Part with VAR (r))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses the [moment-generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) of a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @vergiom no prob! Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.